# I cant trigger submit button on javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<form action="'.$return.'" method="post">
<input name="msgtype" type="text" value="" class="form-control hidden" >
<input name="msg" type="text" value="" class="form-control hidden" >
<button id="gonder" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "></button>
</form>


 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gonder').trigger('click');
});</script>
```

It's for php automatic info system. and When it comes trouble it will post and show message on previous page.. Thats what I wanna do.. But javascript code dont work.. what did I do wrong?

its the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Online Restoran İslem Merkezi</title>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start(); ob_start(); 
include ('mysql.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 

    echo '<form action="'.$return.'" method="post">
    <input name="msgtype" type="text" value="danger" class="form-control hidden" >
    <input name="msg" type="text" value="Malzeme seçme limitini aştınız." class="form-control hidden" >
    <button id="gonder" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "></button>
    </form>';
    echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#gonder').trigger('click');
});</script>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try `$('form').submit()` instead, as that's the event you really seem to want to trigger

Comment: `.trigger('click')` will invoke the click event bound with it. If you want to invoke the physical `click`, then just use `.click()` over the extracted js object. A procedural example http://jsfiddle.net/hn6vndjs/

Comment: try this $("form").trigger("submit");

Comment: doesnt work all I tried everything... thats the full code I edited

Comment: your script not work, because you generating it through php. Try to put your script separate from php code.

Comment: I did but It doesnt work anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try

$(document).ready(function(){ $('#gonder').click(); });

Comment: As discussed in the comment, it will invoke the click event bound with the relevant element. Also, there is no difference between `.click()` and `.trigger('click')`

Comment: doesnt work all I tried everything... thats the full code I edited

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="myform" action="'.$return.'" method="post">
    <input name="msgtype" type="text" value="danger" class="form-control hidden" >
    <input name="msg" type="text" value="Malzeme seçme limitini aştınız." class="form-control hidden" >
    <button id="gonder" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary "></button>
    </form>';
    <script>
  document.myform.submit();</script>
```

It work like that.. Thanks Anyway